# Excel 2010 equation editor object access through vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, ms-word, office-2007

In Excel 2010 the equation editor is not listed in the Object Browser. In Word, the object is called OMath http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb256563%28office.12%29.aspx. Maybe Excel uses a Word object to display equations?

So the questions are:

1. Is there any way to access that object in Excel if said object is not in the object browser?
2. Specifically about the equation editor, is there any way to access it from vba in excel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2007, when you want to insert an equation, you have to insert an `Object` > `Microsoft Excel Equation Editor 3.0`. See on [MSDN](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-equation-editor-in-excel-HP010215799.aspx) on how to use this.

You can add a new Equation with:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Equation.3", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
```

You can access these objects within the `OLEObjects collection`:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Item(1)
```

It seems like Microsoft doesn't handle equations in the same way between Excel and Word (2007 at least) because Excel doesn't use the `OMath` object.

Comment: My bad, Excel 2007 hadn't yet gained the new equation editor. The Word 2007+ style equation editor first appeared in Excel 2010.

So the question remains, obviously for Excel 2010. @JMax Thanks!